# creating vim plugins

Tags: vim, plugin

I would like to attempt my first VIM plugin and wondered where there are some good docs on this? From going threw the plugins I use it seems to me that it is a mix of BASH and some sorts of VIM api is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Steve Losh wrote a nice introduction for creating vim plugins](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2011/09/writing-vim-plugins/). He mentions common pitfalls, strategies and further information sources.

AFAIK it is not necessarily a mix of bash script and vim API. A plugin is either written in the programming language [Vim script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimscript) or in another scripting language, e.g. Python. For a plugin written in Python your vim needs to be compiled with Python support - thus, such a plugin is less portable between different vim installations.

Via [Vim script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimscript) you can call external processes, including shell scripts.